# How do European to American outlet change frequency?

Tags: transformer

So for the transforming of voltage, a transformer could get a european outlet from 240 to 120 volts. How do these switch the frequency though, do they have to convert it into DC and then generate a signal back to AC? Or is there an easier way? Or do they just leave it at 50 hertz assuming everything is going to work properly?

Comment: You need to clean up the English in your question to reduce confusion. For example, a transformer doesn't "get" a outlet, whether european or not. I think I see what you're asking, but I shouldn't have to guess and re-read the question a few times. You should take a little care and show a little respect when you're asking for a favor (free help in this case). Think of what the teacher would say if you handed in a homework assignment like this. Even if the teacher lets you get away with this, *we* have the right to some respect here.

Comment: sorry i was really tired when I asked it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the frequency is critical to the operation of the device there is no attempt to change the frequency so all that is needed is a transformer with a 2: 1 ratio. Most devices simply change the AC to DC at a lower voltage. As the two frequencies are quite close there is usually no problem with circuit values.

Comment: Notice that the simplest devices of all don't even have a mains transformer, they just convert the plug's "form factor".

Comment: @jippie - you are quite correct - the very simplest don't even use a transformer. Many devices also have a built in switch so you can select the working voltage.